# Compiling without the Crashlytics Mac App?

Tags: ios, iphone, crashlytics

I have to train some people on our iOS platform, and am trying to get them up to speed asap during a training session.

However, in order to properly run the app from Xcode, the Crashlytics 
plugin is needed. Otherwise, the project won't compile and that kinda sucks.

I'm guessing one alternative would be to set up accounts for everybody, 
have them download the plugin, properly link it to the app, and we'd be 
fine. 
BUT, is there another way around this? **Is there some way to have them 
running the app without the Mac App and all that hassle?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wont removing the Crashlytics run script from Build Settings work ?

Comment: Mm it's possible. But I'd prefer to avoid changing the project in any way. I'll try though and have it as a last resource if it works.

Comment: @Xcoder post it as an answer and if there's no better alternative I'll approve it... It worked obviously, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike from Crashlytics here. If the team won't be building any release configurations during the training session, then adding Conditional Logic around the Run Script is the best way to go. Note, that no crash reports would come through.

```
releaseConfig="Release"

if [ "$releaseConfig" = "${CONFIGURATION}" ]; then   
    echo "Running Crashlytics"
    ./Crashlytics.framework/run {your_api_key_here}
fi
```

[Taken from here.](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/118559-can-i-make-the-dsym-uploading-only-on-release-buil)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It never occurred to me that the dsym question would be useful in this case :s. Essentially this would be similar to @fguchelaar answer, right?

Comment: Correct, it is a similar answer, but @fguchelaar answer would mean Crashlytics would only run once. DSYMs would never be upload aside from the very first run.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the 'Run script only when installing' checkbox on the Build Phases tab of the Target's properties.

[image: Run script only when installing]

That way you can run the App in the simulator without any hassle.

Comment: If I leave this configuration will it still be linked to Crashlytics when I release a new version or is it necessary to revert the change?

Comment: the script will run when you `Archive` your project, so you should be safe!

Comment: As @MikeB points out in the other answer, this solution would only upload info on the very first run, even if you close the app and run it again.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the Crashlytics run script from the Build Settings of your project.

Comment: Although this works it is necessary to revert the change later.